# How to connect on VNC client to non-default display (:1)

Tags: gui, virtualization, vnc, remmina

#### Context

I'm working with a friend to run a virtual machine on a remote server and connect to it using VNC.

As he already have one VM on the `:0` display, he put mine on the `:1` display.

## Issue

I tried to connect to the machine using various VNC client (`remmina`, `tightvnc`, `krdc`) and none seems to be able to connect to a display other than `:0`.

N.B. : I also tried `virt-manager` but it seems the gentoo server doesn't have the right version of `netstat`.

Answer (score 1):

For now, the only client that seems to support that is `xvnc4viewer` where I put in thue VNC server field :

> server_hostname:1

Answer (score 0):

Remmina supports host{name,ip}:display.  For example the server text field could hold 10.10.10.10:1 which would connect, via VNC, to VNC display 1 (port 5901) on the host t 10.10.10.10